# Equatable protocol implementation for undefined property list?

Tags: swift, reflection, compare, mirror, equatable

I have a class with `Equatable` protocol implementation. I know that 2 objects of this class are equal if all their inner variables are equal. Objects may contain arrays. Currently I hardcode each value pair comparison which is not agile.

If there is a way to implement such comparison by iterating through the property list? For example with `Mirror` (reflection)?

Comment: What can be the case where you don't know the properties in the object where you're conforming Equatable. Kindly specify the scenario as well.

Comment: the list is big and is not finished. So otherwise I need to rewrite `==` operator each time I remove or add a new property and it is not agile

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have a `struct Person`,

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}
```

Now you can conform the `Equatable protocol` in it like,

```
extension Person: Equatable {
    public static func == (lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        let children1 = Mirror(reflecting: lhs).children
        let children2 = Mirror(reflecting: rhs).children

        for child1 in children1 {
            let value1 = child1.value
            if let value2 = children2.first(where: { $0.label == child1.label })?.value {
                if String(describing: value1) != String(describing: value2) {
                    return false
                }
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

In the above code, I'm comparing `String` values of both `value1` and `value2`. This is not exactly the right way to do it. But I had to since `value1` and `value2` are of `Any` type and hence cannot be compared directly. So, the solution might not work for custom types inside `Person`.

This is just a way out in case you don't want to compare all the properties individually.

**Usage:**

```
let p1 = Person(name: "Name1", age: 10, designation: nil)
let p2 = Person(name: "Name1", age: 10, designation: "SE")
print(p1 == p2)
```

Comment: What to do if `Person` contains `var data: [PersonData]`, where `PersonData` implements `Equatable` via the same way? I try create `[PersonData]` with one element (but such elements contain different inner data) and your code says that 2 `Person` are equal